# Reconnecting with pySerial

Tags: python, pyserial, reconnect

I'm trying to write a function which continuously reads serial input. The function must be able to handle unexpected disconnections from the serial port and reconnect when possible. Despite reading several question posts on stackOverflow and looking through the pySerial documentation, I have yet to find a solution.

Here's my code:

```
def serialRead(serialPort, queue):
    """Adds serial port input to a queue."""

    ser = serial.Serial(serialPort - 1, timeout = 2)

    ser.parity = "O"
    ser.bytesize = 7

    while(True):
        try:
            if(ser == None):
                ser = serial.Serial(serialPort - 1, timeout = 2)

                ser.parity = "O"
                ser.bytesize = 7

                print("Reconnecting")

            queue.put(ser.read(27))
            ser.write(chr(6).encode())

            print("Writing Data...")

        except:
            if(not(ser == None)):
                ser.close()
                ser = None
                print("Disconnecting")

            print("No Connection")
            time.sleep(2)
```

Here's my output:

```
Enter a Serial Port: 7
Writing Data...
Writing Data...
Writing Data...
Writing Data...
```

I start with my device connected. After leaving the program run, neither "Disconnecting" or "No Connection" display and the program stops (it doesn't crash).

Comment: How are you exiting the program?

Comment: I'm not exiting the program. I'm trying to write the program so that it continues to run, even if the connection is lost.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood "leaving the program run". So what does happen when you disconnect whatever's connected to the port?

Comment: I have my output in the post. Do you need clarification?

Comment: Do you ever disconnect the device from your computer while the program is running?

Comment: Yes, that's how I got my output.

Comment: So to make sure I fully understand your problem: After you disconnect the device, it continues to output "Writing Data...", or does it stop completely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57507/discussion-between-batman-and-raeven).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works. Batman tested the program on an Arduino connection and I found that my program had successfully reconnected with the device after a period of time. I hope this code will be useful for those struggling with something similar.